# how do I pass the View/Model/Projection matrices to my vertex shader in OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, opengl-es, iphone-3gs

In [OpenGL ES 2.0](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/), you apparently can't do

```
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
```

any more to set the model matrix, but I think these matrices are still built in somehow, since the [GLSL spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.Full.1.20.8.pdf) tells you how to access them in a vertex shader.

```
// 
// Matrix state. p. 31, 32, 37, 39, 40. 
// 
uniform mat4  gl_ModelViewMatrix; 
uniform mat4  gl_ProjectionMatrix; 
uniform mat4  gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix;
```

so how do I pass these values to my shader?  do I use `glUniformMatrix4fv` somehow?

The source code from the [OpenGL ES 2.0 Programming Guide](http://www.opengles-book.com/) has been helpful for the shader part but all the examples appear to just leave the matrix transforms alone and just make sure their vertices are between -1.0 and 1.0.

UPDATE: apparently the [OpenGL ES Shader Language](http://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf) does *not* support the pre-defined entries like `gl_ModelViewMatrix`, so the only answer is to define your own custom model/view/projection matrices as done in the code linked below, using `glGetUniformLocation` and `glUniformMatrix4fv`.  I was confused because the OpenGL Shader Builder *does* support them, but that's plain OpenGL, not OpenGL ES.

Answer (score 0):

gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix does not appear to be in the "**OpenGL ES Shading Language** version 1.00" specification.  There seems to be many Shading Language specifications, so that likely was the cause of confusion.  As I understand it, you define your own uniforms for matrix storage.